# Notifying github watchers when an issue is posted

Tags: github

Is there a way to notify the watchers of a github repo when an issue is posted?  Ideally, automatically?

<sub>(The people watching [giving.github.com](http://giving.github.com/) presumably do so in order to be notified when issues are posted, and not to know when the web-pages are updated!)</sub>

Comment: Everyone watching will automatically get notified of new issues and pull requests on the repo

Answer (score 0):

Current solution:

Manually, from the command-line in a cloned repo:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "issue #2 posted"
git push
```

This will hopefully notify everyone and they get a hyperlink straight to the issue, but its not automatic.